# Each element is a square of some element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have to show that each element of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is a square of some element.

Could you give me some hints how I could do that??

Comment: A map from a finite set to itself is surjective if and only if it is injective.

Comment: In most fields the squaring function $x\mapsto x^2$ is two-to-one.  That implies that only half of the non-zero elements can be squares.  In fields in which $\forall x\  x=-x$, the function is one-to-one.

Comment: Ok!! Thank you both!!! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the map $\phi : \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \to \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ given by $\phi(x) = x^2$. You can show that this is a homomorphism between rings (use the fact that $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{F}_{2^n}) = 2$), so its kernel is an ideal in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. As $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is a field, $\ker\phi = \{0\}$ or $\ker\phi = \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, but you should be able to rule out the latter by demonstrating an element in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ which has non-zero square. Once you have done this, you see that $\phi$ is an isomorphism; in particular, it is surjective.

Comment: Could you explain me further how to find $\ker \phi$?? It stands that $$\ker \phi =\{x \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \text{ with } x^2=0 \}$$ right??

Comment: The kernel of a ring homomorphism is always an ideal. The only ideals in a field are the zero ideal and the whole field, so $\ker\phi = \{0\}$ or $\ker\phi = \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. If you can give an example of an element of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ which has non-zero square (e.g. $1$), then $\ker\phi \neq \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ so we must have $\ker\phi = \{0\}$.

Comment: So, to find the $\ker \phi$ we have to use the ideals, right?? We cannot find it using the definition above, right??

Comment: I suppose that depends on how explicit your description of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is. One way to do it is to use Martin Brandenburg's approach. If $x^2 = 0$, then $x = x^{2^n} = (x^2)^{2^{n-1}} = 0^{2^{n-1}} = 0$ so $x = 0$.

Comment: Ok! I see. $$$$ We have shown that $\ker \phi=\{0\}$ that means that the homomorphism is one-to-one, right? How do show that is also onto?

Comment: If $X$ is a finite set, an injective function $X \to X$ is automatically bijective.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 7):

In $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$  every element $x$ satisfies $x^{q^n}=x$. In fact, for $x=0$ this is clear, and for $x \neq 0$ it follows from Lagrange's theorem applied to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}^\times$. In particular, every element of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is a square.

Comment: So, we have that $$x \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n} : x^{2^n}=x$$ But how can we write it as a square?? I got stuck right now...

Comment: @MaryStar: $2^n=2^{n-1}\cdot 2$...

Comment: @HenningMakholm So, is it as followed?? $$x^{2^n}=x \Rightarrow x=x^{2 \cdot 2^{n-1}} \Rightarrow x= \left (x^{2^{n-1}} \right )^2$$

Comment: @MaryStar: Yes.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot!!! So, one way to show this is to take the identity of an element of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ and an other is to take a ring homomorphism, right??

Comment: @MaryStar: I have no idea what you are asking. Also, please refrain from using "???" or "!!!". Really, one "?" or "!" suffices.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $\phi : \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \to \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ given by $\phi(x) = x^2$.

Then, $\phi$ is injective because $x^2=y^2$ iff $0=x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=(x-y)^2$. Since there are no zero divisors in a field, $x-y=0$ and so $x=y$.

Since the field is finite, $\phi$ is surjective and every element is a square.

Comment: Could you explain me why the following equality stand?? $$(x+y)(x-y)=(x-y)^2$$

Comment: @MaryStar, $y=-y$ in characteristic $2$ and so $x+y=x-y$.

Comment: We have shown that $\phi$ is one-to-one. Could you explain me how we conclude that it is also onto?

Comment: @MaryStar, if $X$ is finite, then a function $X \to X$ is injective iff it is bijective because the image has the same number of elements as $X$.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!!!! :-)